# ¿Como insertar multiples valores pero separados en un solo registro MariaDb?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mariadb

Hola quiero insertar multiples productos, unidades, cantidades, fechas relacionadas por su misma orden de compra para despues poderlas mostrar dentro de una misma fila en una tabla, pero no encuentro como hacerlo. Basicamente es un sistema para capturar pedidos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Para ser mas claro que si tuvieran la misma orden de compra se juntaran dentro de la misma fila de la tabla, y se mostraran juntos los productos, unidades, cantidades etcetera asociados a la misma orden de compra y los demas separados pero dentro de la misma tabla. Por ahí leí que es malo usar arrays dentro de la base de datos ya que la misma base de datos es como un array. Les dejo mis tablas:

```
 CREATE TABLE capturar_pedido (
        cliente varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        orden_de_compra varchar(255),
        producto varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        unidad varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        cantidad varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        fecha_de_embarque Date NOT NULL,
        notas varchar(255),
        etiquetado char(2) NOT NULL,

        id_pedido BIGINT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY (id_pedido)
        )


        CREATE TABLE salida_materiales (


        folio varchar(255) NOT NULL,

        fecha Date NOT NULL,
        numero_remision varchar(255),
        numero_factura varchar(255),
        otro varchar(255),
        referencia_transporte varchar(255),
        placa_tractor varchar(255),
        placa_caja varchar(255),
        comentarios varchar(255),
        retorno char(2),
        fecha_posible Date NOT NULL,
        orden_de_compra varchar(255) not null UNIQUE,
        id_materiales BIGINT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY (id_materiales),
        FOREIGN KEY(orden_de_compra) references capturar_pedido(orden_de_compra))


    CREATE TABLE coa (

    fecha Date NOT NULL,
    presentacion varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    cantidad varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    oc varchar(255),

    lote varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    produccion varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    caducidad varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    sello varchar(255),
    apariencia varchar(255),
    resultado_apariencia varchar(255),
    sabor varchar(255),
    resultado_sabor varchar(255),
    olor varchar(255),
    resultado_olor varchar(255),
    color varchar(255),
    resultado_color varchar(255),
    pureza varchar(255),
    resultado_pureza varchar(255),
    humedad varchar(255),
    resultado_humedad varchar(255),
    id_pedido Bigint(10) not null UNIQUE,

    id_coa BIGINT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

    PRIMARY KEY (id_coa),

    FOREIGN KEY(id_pedido) references capturar_pedido(id_pedido)


    )


    CREATE TABLE granulometria (

    parametro varchar(255),
    unidad varchar(255),
    especificacion varchar(255),
    resultado varchar(255),
    id_pedido int(10) not null,//hacerla foreign key pero no unica
    id_granulometria BIGINT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_granulometria)
    )
```

Comment: Creo que quieres relacionar la visualización de los datos con el almacenamiento y no tienen porque guardar relación. La estructura de la BD y tablas en un sistema relacional sigue unas normas, sino las sigues tendrás graves problemas... La visualización de los datos la organizas a partir de los datos, según se requiera. Puedes tener un problema con el diseño de tu base de datos; lo habitual es tener una tabla 'pedidos', con datos generales y otra con 'lineas_pedido', y en cada registro de esta un artículo del pedido, que lleva a la primera tabla mediante una clave ajena.
Saludos.

Comment: @Orici Y que hay de mi BD cual es el error?, depues de hecho el pedido debera quedar almacenado con todos sus campos y no encontre mejor forma que guardarlo registro por registro, si tienen la misma orden  de compra(mismo pedido)uso el mismo parametro x veces en php

Answer (score 0):

Tu bd debe seguir un esquema similar a este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tanto los "clientes" como los "productos", pueden existir sin necesidad de que haya pedidos, por tanto son tablas sin claves ajenas.

Un "pedido" requiere de la existencia de un "cliente", tiene una clave ajena a la ID de la tabla "clientes". Además, un pedido puede estar compuesto de 1 o múltiples productos, de ahí la necesidad de una tabla que guarde los detalles de compra para cada producto, como la cantidad adquirida, tenemos la tabla "linea_pedido". Esta tabla contiene dos claves ajenas, una para saber a que pedido pertenece cada línea y otra para saber el "producto" adquirido.

SQL crear las tablas de la imagen:

```
CREATE TABLE productos (
    id          INT(12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre      VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    descripcion VARCHAR(255)    DEFAULT NULL,
    unidades    ENUM( 'ltrs', 'kgs' ) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'kgs',
    cantidad_env FLOAT(6.3)     NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    precio_ud   DECIMAL(9.2)    NOT NULL,
    stock       INT(12)         NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,

    created_at  TIMESTAMP   DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    deleted_at  TIMESTAMP   DEFAULT 0,
    modified_at TIMESTAMP   DEFAULT 0,

    UNIQUE( nombre, cantidad_env ),
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE clientes (
    id          INT(12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre      VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    email       VARCHAR(255)    DEFAULT NULL,
    telefono    VARCHAR(100)    DEFAULT NULL,
    direccion   VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    password    VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,

    created_at  TIMESTAMP   DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    deleted_at  TIMESTAMP   DEFAULT 0,
    modified_at TIMESTAMP   DEFAULT 0,

    UNIQUE( nombre, email ),
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE pedidos (
    id          INT(12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    referencia  VARCHAR(100)    DEFAULT NULL,
    cliente_id  INT(12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    notas       VARCHAR(255)    DEFAULT NULL,

    created_at  TIMESTAMP   DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    deleted_at  TIMESTAMP   DEFAULT 0,
    modified_at TIMESTAMP   DEFAULT 0,

    FOREIGN KEY ( cliente_id ) REFERENCES clientes( id )
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE linea_pedido (
    id          INT(12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    pedido_id   INT(12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    producto_id INT(12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    cantidad    INT(12)         NOT NULL,

    created_at  TIMESTAMP   DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    deleted_at  TIMESTAMP   DEFAULT 0,
    modified_at TIMESTAMP   DEFAULT 0,

    FOREIGN KEY ( pedido_id ) REFERENCES pedidos( id )
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY ( producto_id ) REFERENCES productos( id )
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Código SQL: https://bitbucket.org/Orici/bd__e-shop